# Android RTL translation with placeholders

Tags: android, android-studio, right-to-left

I’m trying to edit my android strings.xml file with arabic translations. However, I’m having issues. For example, I have something like this:

```
<string name="test">اختبار</string>
```

When I type something like **%1$s** to add a placeholder, the string with the placeholder is also mixed up.

What’s the right approach to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placeholders (ascii) in BiDi strings are tricky. If you know that this `%1$s` will eventually be substituted by a name in Arabic, it's manageable; but if the substitution can be English or mixed text, you need a long and careful QA to check all special cases.

Don't try to edit Arabic text in Android Studio text editor for file **res/values-ar/strings.xml**; use the Translations Editor instead.

The official guide *https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html*  describes the this editor in great detail, but one little trick that it misses is the use of **View/BiDi Text Direction** menu. To work with Arabic strings, you want to set it to Right-to-Left.

This will not effect the Arabic column in your Editor, and not even the way the translation is displayed in the text box at the bottom:

[image: bottom text]

But when you click the <kbd>**...**</kbd> button for translation, you will get the translation in RTL:

[image: translation pop-up]

Now you can understand how your placeholder(s) will look when replaced with actual data.

Comment: could you mention in your answer as to how to work with floating numbers when using rtl string resource? I have a text resource:
<string name="points">%1$.2f نقاط</string>

Comment: There should be nothing very special for floating format. Your example looks legit, but are you sure that your user expects 'european' digits and not [Indic digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals)?

Comment: my worry was should the placeholder also be RTL, like: f2.$1% or LTR like it is already? Also, to answer your question, when I placed the above string resource in the Arabic strings.xml it automatically converted to Arabic number system.

Comment: The placeholder itself should be LTR as in your first example. It's nice that the platform handles the digit substitution for you, but be careful: in the ideal world, this should actually depend on the Locale. Some Arab countries prefer these digits, others (مغرب) don't.